# How to test changes made by onClick event that calls a setState function, which is passed from another component and changes UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Basically the title.

Here is the overview of the `App`:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isViewFavoriteImages, setIsViewFavoriteImages] = useState(false);

  const toggleIsViewFavoriteImages = () => {
    setIsViewFavoriteImages(
      (prevToggleIsViewFavoriteImagesState) =>
        !prevToggleIsViewFavoriteImagesState
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <ToggleImagesViewButton
          toggleIsViewFavoriteImages={toggleIsViewFavoriteImages}
          isViewFavoriteImages={isViewFavoriteImages}
        />
        <ImageList isViewFavoriteImages={isViewFavoriteImages} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The button component:

```
export interface ToggleImageViewButtonProps {
  toggleIsViewFavoriteImages: () => void;
  isViewFavoriteImages: boolean;
}

const ToggleImageViewButton: React.FC<ToggleImageViewButtonProps> = ({
  toggleIsViewFavoriteImages,
  isViewFavoriteImages,
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={toggleIsViewFavoriteImages}
      className="btn btn_toggle-image-view"
      data-testid="toggle-image-view"
    >
      {isViewFavoriteImages ? "view all" : "view favorites"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ToggleImageViewButton;
```

And this is how I am testing it:

```
function renderToggleImagesViewButton(
  props: Partial<ToggleImageViewButtonProps> = {}
) {
  const defaultProps: ToggleImageViewButtonProps = {
    toggleIsViewFavoriteImages: () => {
      return;
    },
    isViewFavoriteImages: true,
  };
  return render(<ToggleImageViewButton {...defaultProps} {...props} />);
}

describe("<ToggleImagesViewButton />", () => {
  test("button inner text should change to 'view all' when the user clicks the button", async () => {
    const onToggle = jest.fn();

    const { findByTestId } = renderToggleImagesViewButton({
      toggleIsViewFavoriteImages: onToggle,
    });

    const toggleImagesViewButton = await findByTestId("toggle-image-view");

    fireEvent.click(toggleImagesViewButton);

    expect(toggleImagesViewButton).toHaveTextContent("view favorites");
  });
});
```

This test fails and `"view all"` is still getting returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToggleImageViewButton` doesn't have internal state - the state was lifted to the parent, so testing state changes should happen in the parent's tests.

You could have the following integration test to verify the correct behaviour of the button when used in `App`.

```js
test("App test", () => {
    render(<App />);
    const button = screen.getByTestId("toggle-image-view");
    expect(button).toHaveTextContent("view favorites");
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(button).toHaveTextContent("view all");
});
```

As for the `ToggleImageViewButton` unit tests, you can simply test that it renders the right text based on `isViewFavoriteImages` value, and that the callback gets called when the button is clicked.

```js
test("ToggleImageViewButton test", () => {
    const onToggle = jest.fn();
    render(<ToggleImageViewButton isViewFavoriteImages={false} toggleIsViewFavoriteImages={onToggle}/>);
    expect(screen.getByTestId("toggle-image-view")).toHaveTextContent("view favorites");
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("toggle-image-view"));
    expect(onToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```